# Find permutations of a given set of numbers whose sum APPROACH a target number

Tags: java, set, permutation, dynamic-programming

Suppose a given set `s = {2,3,4}` and target `sum = 8`
I want to find all possible permutations whose sum APPROACH the target. I mean the sum is between:
target minus the smallest number in the set (8-2) and target plus the largest number in the set (8+4) i.e: (sum>=6) and (sum<=8). The result should be the following:

```
2   2   2   2
2   2   3   
2   2   4   
2   3   2   
2   3   3   
2   4   2   
3   2   2   
3   2   3   
3   3   2   
3   4   2   
4   2       
4   3       
4   4
```

I have to write the code in Java. I think it can be done through recursion. I have seen the examples like finding a subset from a set whose sum equals to a target but my problem is different from that.
After a lot of tries I failed to build the logic.

Right now I am doing it in a very naive way using the following code. However, I would like to improve it.

```
package com.main;

public class MainClass {

static int sum =0;

static void setSum(){
    sum=0;
}

public static void perm2(int[] set, int target)
{
    int min=set[0];
    int max=set[0];

    for(int jj=0; jj<set.length; jj++){
        if(min>set[jj])
            min=set[jj];
        if(max<set[jj])
            max=set[jj];
    }

    int i=0;    
    do{ 
        if(sum<target){
            sum +=set[i];

            int j=0;
            do{
                sum =set[i]+set[j];

                if(sum>min+max)
                    if(sum<=target){
                        System.out.println(set[i]+","+set[j]);  

                    }else
                    {setSum();j=set.length;}

                j++;    
            }while(j<set.length);

        }else
        {setSum(); i=set.length;}

        i++;
    }while(i<set.length);
}

public static void perm3(int[] set, int target){

    int i=0;    
    do{         
        if(sum<target){
            sum +=set[i];                   
            int j=0;
            do{
                sum =set[i]+set[j];
                if(sum<target){

                    int k=0;
                    do{

                        sum =set[i]+set[j]+set[k];
                        if(sum<=target)                                 
                            System.out.println(set[i]+","+set[j]+","+set[k]);   
                        else
                        {setSum();k=set.length;}

                        k++;    
                    }while(k<set.length);

                }else
                {setSum();j=set.length;}

                j++;    
            }while(j<set.length);

        }else
        {setSum(); i=set.length;}

        i++;
    }while(i<set.length);

    perm2(set,target);
}

public static void perm4(int[] set, int target){    
    int i=0;    
    do{

        if(sum<target){
            sum +=set[i];                   
            int j=0;
            do{

                if(sum<target){
                    sum =set[i]+set[j];                         
                    int k=0;
                    do{
                        if(sum<target){
                            sum =set[i]+set[j]+set[k];  
                            int l=0;
                            do{
                                sum =set[i]+set[j]+set[k]+set[l];
                                if(sum<=target){

                                    System.out.println(set[i]+","+set[j]+","+set[k]+","+set[l]);

                                }else
                                {setSum();l=set.length;}


                                l++;    
                            }while(l<set.length);


                        }else
                        {setSum();k=set.length;}

                        k++;    
                    }while(k<set.length);


                }else
                {setSum();j=set.length;}

                j++;    
            }while(j<set.length);

        }else
        {setSum(); i=set.length;}

        i++;
    }while(i<set.length);

    perm3(set, target);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] set = new int[]{2,3,4};
    int target = 8;

    perm4(set, target);

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've written?

Comment: We don't just write code for you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CombinatoricsLib 2.1 is a java library for generating combinatorial objects. It is based on java generics and doesn't depend on other libraries. You should only include this library into your project and set the specific type of elements of the permutations or combinations.

https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/